# Why is code after `else` in a multi-line conditional considered valid ruby syntax?

Tags: ruby, syntax

I was surprised to see that (in Ruby 2.7.4) it is possible to add code after the `else` keyword, as I've never encountered this before.  The following code is considered valid by ruby's built-in syntax checker, and runs quite happily:

```rb
if false
  puts 'noop'
else puts 'why is this possible'; 'not returned'
  puts 'and not a syntax error?'
  'returned'
end

# # Output
# why is this possible
# and not a syntax error?
# => "returned"
```

The in-line code after `else` is interpreted (`puts 'why is this possible'`) , but the result (`'not returned'`) is discarded.

However if I add `return` to the `else` line things get really unexpected:

```rb
if false
  puts 'noop'
else puts 'why is this possible'; return 'inline returned'
  puts 'this is now not called'
  'not returned'
end

# # Output
# why is this possible
# => "inline returned"
```

I don't know what this would be called, so I'm unable to google it – I can't find this documented or mentioned anywhere and don't know if it is an intentional language feature (possibly a side-effect of the single-line `if/then/else` syntax...?).

Can anybody shed any light on why this works, and if there is a valid use-case for it?

Comment: I'd say code after `else` is perfectly valid if the code you're adding is syntactically valid. As there's no other keyword (like `if`) after the `else` then the parser does it right and works the same as if you'd put a break line after it.
In the 1st example "not returned" is not used for anything, so Ruby does what the code tells it to do. If you do `...; puts 'not returned'` you'll see it's printed.

Comment: Does the code makes sense to you if you replace the space after `else` with the newline? Well, that's it :) From the parser's point of view, both newline and space are just valid whitespaces separating `else` from the branch code itself...

Comment: To add a note which wasn't very explicit: Ruby will automatically return the last item in a method, so in the first case `"returned"` is said item. If you manually declare a return as done in your second example the automatic/implicit return will be overwritten.

Comment: "From the parser's point of view, both newline and space are just valid whitespaces separating else from the branch code itself." <- this is what I was missing, thanks @KonstantinStrukov. Somehow I never knew these were the same, and was expecting something along the lines of `syntax error: unexpected X, expecting end-of-input` on the `else` line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be more obvious with explicit line breaks. Your first example is equivalent to:

```
if false
  puts 'noop'
else
  puts 'why is this possible'
  'not returned'
  puts 'and not a syntax error?'
  'returned'
end
```

The `'not returned'` string literal doesn't do anything on its own. What's left are two `puts` calls and a return value of `'returned'`.

Your second example:

```
if false
  puts 'noop'
else
  puts 'why is this possible'
  return 'inline returned'
  puts 'this is now not called'
  'not returned'
end
```

Here, the `return` keyword will exit the enclosing method after the first `puts` call right-away with a return value of `'inline returned'`. Hence, the following `puts` and the implicit return value of `'not returned'` are ignored.

Comment: Technically, `'not returned'` is shot into outer space.

Comment: Somehow despite writing ruby for over 10 years I never knew that space and newline were syntactically equivalent in this case. I always thought that the newline after `else` was in some way part of the syntax requirement, similar to after the `if ...` clause: 

`if true 'this is invalid syntax' else 'no' end` 

...is _not_ valid and returns "syntax error, unexpected `else', expecting end-of-input" which is what I had been expecting in my example. It makes more sense now but still doesn't sit quite right!